# m4.large not ebsOptimized

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, aws-cli

M4 large instances are EBS-optimized by default as per below URL :

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

When I try to check the status using aws-cli I get result with boolean value set to false. The command I used is as below :

```
ec2-describe-instance-attribute i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --ebs-optimized --aws-access-key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --aws-secret-key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Result of above command :

```
ebsOptimized i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx false
```

Is it the correct way to verify if the instance is EBS optimized? Please help me to verify if the instance is EBS optimized.

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: @Tim Console also has EBS-optimized set to False

Comment: How did you launch it?

Comment: I'd post this question on the AWS forums. It's an odd one.

Comment: Thank you for the replies and suggestions. I figured out that the instance was created using Auto-scaling group which had Launch configuration with the EBS-Optimized option unchecked.